Pin the calendar of Outlook Windows App (new) to taskbar
I have been trying to pin the calendar of the Windows 11 Outlook (new) app to the taskbar. Checked some online forums, but no success. The calendar can open in new windows but why can't I pin it to separate quick access taskbar? (pinning the Outlook web version is slow and buggy).
This is important as I frequently shuffle from my emails to calendar to check my schedule and add appointments. Anybody knows a way around it?

As i know, it's not available in New Outlook for Windows. You can vote for the feedback on the website dedicated to collecting feedback.

